# Cast constant value from series

Tags: constants, pine-script, series, volume

I'm completely new to this forum and tradingview/pinescript. I am trying to script an indicator, and part of the script requires assigning a constant value to a variable from a series.

From a moving average of the volume (50day average volume), I want to set the constant variable 'reference_Vol' to the value of the moving average from yesterday's price bar only and no other days in the past before yesterday, but the variable gets overwritten after each older bar as 'volume' is a series, so effectively the variable is not constant but dynamically changes over the history of the price bars.

```
SMA_50d = sma(volume,50)
reference_Vol =SMA_50d[1]
```

I have tried setting the value as a literal (literal int(x)), messing around with the valuewhen() function, but I have just not enough scripting experience of what I am doing. I have a feeling there is an easy solution to this, and I could really use some help.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you intended

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=false)

var float   reference_Vol = na
new_day = ta.change(dayofmonth)

SMA_50d = ta.sma(volume,50)

if new_day
    reference_Vol := SMA_50d[1]

plot(reference_Vol, style=plot.style_linebr, color=new_day ? na : color.blue)
```

Comment: Hi Bjorn, thanks for your help - unfortunately this still produces a series, if only the last value is plotted because the plot color is conditional. What I need essentially is that the value (of the 50d volume MA) from yesterday is taken out of the series and written into a constant variable. After this has happened for one time, it should not be overwritten anymore, hence I either need a constant variable or a series/array that has the same value for every element (=yesterdays volume 50d-MA value). By 'yesterday' I mean the singular yesterday, not every yesterday for every bar in the past.

Comment: That cannot be done, because the script runs on every bar. That's the reason why it's still a series. Also, you cannot know what 'yesterday' is, because there's no way of knowing when the last bar will come, just like in real life.